# How run firefox from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, firefox

How run firefox on Ubuntu 15 from Node.js?

This working on OSX but is not working on Ubuntu.

```
var open = require("open");
open("http://www.google.com", "Firefox");
```

This code executing without errors, but Firefox is not opening.
Maybe problem with rights?

Comment: Do you have an executable named `Firefox`? Does typing `Firefox` on the command line work?

Comment: Firefox from the command line is working!

Comment: Are you sure it is `Firefox` that is working and not `firefox`?

Comment: use firefox not Firefox ....

Comment: Sorry, "firefox" - is working from command line!
open("http://www.google.com", "firefox"); - not working too.

Comment: Slimerjs "nodejs" version - working on OSX, but not open Firefox from Node on Ubuntu too.

Comment: The same code is working on my virtual box ... check whether "open" is installed or not ... and open("google.com", "firefox");  is also working ... remove the ';' after the link  "google.com";,

Comment: Open is installed!  ";" - is it not from my code) It added from "stackoverflow".
Node run this code without errors. All modules installed correctly. Maybe problem with chmod?

Comment: Do you know another method open the firefox from node?

Comment: I run node remotely through terminal, maybe in this problem?

Comment: On local machine terminal - node is not open firefox too.

Comment: Solution: 
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('DISPLAY=:0.0 firefox, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
 if (error !== null) {
 console.log('exec error: ' + error);
 }
});

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct code ... ubuntu terminal is case sensitive ...

```
var open = require("open");
open("http://www.google.com", "firefox");
```

Comment: But still not open Firefox on Ubuntu. On OSX is working.